# Loop through all folders and executing script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, filesystem

I have a bash script `install.sh` in my current directory and I have a directory `apps` which contains multiple directories. I want to loop through these sub directories in app folder and execute some script. After executing script in first folder it should come back and enter into next folder. I have tried this but it's skipping one after another. I mean it's entering into all odd folders and not entering into even folders.

Code in `install.sh`

```
for f in apps/*;
  do 
     [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f and installing packages
     cd ..
  done;
```

Comment: It looks like you're descending two levels down but only coming back up one level. Try changing `cd ..` to `cd -`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use full path of your parent directory(in my case `apps` directory located in my home directory) and remove one extra command(`cd ..`)

```bsh
for dir in ~/apps/*;
  do 
     [ -d "$dir" ] && cd "$dir" && echo "Entering into $dir and installing packages"
  done;
```

See screenshot: with `cd ..` command and using `apps/*`

[image]

See screenshot: without `cd ..` command and using `~/apps/*`

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked..``curdir=$(pwd)
for f in $curdir/apps/*;
  do 
     [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f and installing packages
  done;``

Comment: @devo Yes you can also use pwd to get the current directory. thanks ;)

Comment: @KasiyA Can you explain why `cd..` should be removed? shouldn't we go back after going into a directory?

Comment: @banarun He(OP) can also use his own script but he need to use two level back cd command `cd ../..` Because when he cd to `$f` directory now he is in `/path/to/apps/1` directory and after `cd ..` he jumps to `/path/to/apps` directory (now curent directory is `/path/to/apps`) and when the next step of for-loop continue, the command looks the directory `/path/to/apps/apps/*` while that is not exist because ha doens't `apps/apps/*` directory and `[ -d $f ]` will return *false*. now `cd ..` command runs again and he jumps to `/path/to` ...

Comment: ... and next step of for-loop runs and checks for directory `/path/to/apps/*` and he luck and he found directory in `apps` which is `3` (because he lost second index of for-loop for second directory) and this cause he just seen odd folders. And why I removed that(`cd ..`) and used full path of `apps` direcory. note that when you use a path in for-loop (`apps/*`), then this looks for directory `apps/*` in current working directory but when you use the full path, it just looks for dir's in that path not current directory.

Comment: So the solution would be 1: using `cd ../..` instead of `cd ..` (in OP case) or 2: using full path and removing `cd ..`. right? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` along with `exec` for this propose. Your `install.sh` should be

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./apps -type d -exec echo Entering into {} and installing packages \;
```

replace text after `-exec` with your command

for example

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./apps -type d -exec touch {}/test.txt  \;
```

It will loop through app and all its sub-directories and will create a text.txt file